# how to build avr-g++ 4.6.3

Tags: ubuntu, g++, avr

I've beein trying to build avr-g++ 4.6.3, but have only been able to find instructions on how to obtain avr-g++ 4.5.3 (via apt-get).  Anybody know a way to successfully build avr-g++ 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 11.10?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you build avr-g++ 4.5.3? Surely it's the same procedure?

Comment: I actually didn't build 4.5.3, I obtained it with apt-get.  But my same question still applies, since I havent found instructions on how to build avr-g++ 4.6.3.

Comment: ok, pre-edit that's what it said

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build a cross-compile environment as documented on the avr-libc site: http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/install_tools.html

No documentation will be Ubuntu specific as you'll have to fetch and compile the entire tool chain by hand which is platform agnostic.